# How to implement lexicographical order string converter (Longest Increasing Subsequence)?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, lexicographic-ordering

I was recently taking part in some kind of online test from java language.

In one of question, I was asked to implement a function, that given a string will return a minimal number of characters that must be removed from the string to get new lexicographical ordered string.

That mean, when we pass string "banana" to our method, it will return 3.

From word "banana" we need to remove 1st letter ("b"), 3rd letter("n") and 6th letter ("a"), to get string "aan".

There is no possibility to remove fewer letters.

I was trying to figure the solution out for quite a long time but without any effect.

One thing that could work would be checking every possible sub-string from our original string, checking if it is ordered and comparing the number of removed digits but it would be terrible for longer strings.

Any ideas for algorithm?

Comment: This is a problem of [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

Comment: Is it any ordered subsequence or the longest one?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Longest  new lexicographical ordered string possible ultimately leading to minimum deletion of characters.

Comment: @vivek_23 Oh sure! Sorry!